# how to change keyboard appearance in android development for my activity only

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to use the exact keyboard that normally pops up with the same button locations, but I want to change the color/appearance of the buttons.  I've looked at the sample project SoftKeyboard but it doesn't appear as an app on the simulator and I haven't been able to learn much from it.  I need to use input from this custom keyboard, please let me know where I need to be more specific if this is too vague.

If I remade the keyboard in my app, would it be possible to prevent the new keyboard from being replaced with the default, and would I then also have to change the EditText widget?

Comment: "I need to use input from this custom keyboard" -- you cannot force anyone to use any given keyboard.

Comment: unless you rebuild the entire softkeyboard system within your application, you won't be able to do this.

Comment: CommonsWare, I'm not sure what you mean by force to use any given keyboard. Couldn't it work like this: my app runs an activity, goes to a screen where the user will interact with what I want to be the exact shape, layout, and function of androids soft keyboard system but differ in appearance. Are you saying that I would not be able to just put it on the UI permanently and just not do anything that calls the android keyboard? I have an idea of how it may be able to work, I just don't know exactly how to implement it.

Comment: Apps don't choose the user's input method editor, users do.